# How to use a conditional for user based input

Tags: java

In my method calcArea, I must "prompt the user to calculate (1 for Triangle, 2 for Circle, 3 for Rectangle, 0 for none of them). Use the Java scanner to read the input. If the user enters 0, return immediately. Otherwise... Use a conditional, and based on the type of area to be calculated, prompt the user for the dimensions of the object, then call the appropriate area method." This is my assignment for homework, I have tried multiple different ways and can not seem to get it. Thanks for the help in advance! This is my code:

```
public class Area {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner shapes = new Scanner (System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter two values to calculate the area of a triangle: ");
   int n1 = shapes.nextInt();
   int n2 = shapes.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter a value to calculate the area of a circle: ");
   double radius = shapes.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter two values to calculate the area of a rectangle: ");
   int m1 = shapes.nextInt();
   int m2 = shapes.nextInt();

   areaTriangle(n1, n2);
   areaCircle(radius);
   areaRectangle(m1, m2);
}
public static void areaTriangle (int n1, int n2) {
    int areat = (n1 * n2)/2;
    System.out.println("The area of a triangle with your values is: " + areat);
}
public static void areaCircle (double radius) {
    double areac = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
    System.out.println("The area of the circle with your values is: " + areac);
}
public static void areaRectangle (int m1, int m2) {
    int arear = (m1 * m2);
    System.out.println("The area of a rectangle with your values is: " + arear);

}
public static void calcArea () {
    System.out.println("Type 1 for the area of Triangle, 2 for area of Circle, 3 for Rectangle, and 0 for area of none of these.");

      if ()
    }    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
if (i == 1) {
    //Do something
}
if (i == 2) {
    //Do something
}
if (i == 3) {
    //Do something
}
else return;
```

Comment: for that, it would be better to use a switch structure. maybe

Comment: But how would I add what it does? Do I call a method to it?

Comment: And this whole `switch` block has to be in your `calcArea()` method

Comment: I must use if statements for this code though, would I still do the same where the case is?

Comment: Updated answer with `if`s

Answer (score 0):

```
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Type number for area calculation: 1 for Triangle, 2 for Circle, 3 for Rectangle, 0 for none of them\n");
      String m=sc.next();
      switch(m){
      case "0":
          System.out.println("None of them");
          break;
      case "1":
          System.out.println("This is for Triangle"); //write your calculation method or call it here
          break;
      case "2":
          System.out.println("This is for Circle"); //write your calculation method or call it here
          break;
      case "3":
          System.out.println("This is for Rectangle"); //write your calculation method or call it here
          break;
      default: 
          System.out.println("Wrong selection!"); //write your calculation method or call it here
```

This is the easiest approach.

```
if(0==m) System.out.println("None of them");
else if(1==m) areaTriangle(n1,n2);
else if(2==m) areaCircle(radius);
else if(3==m) areaRectangle(m1,m2);
else System.out.println("Wrong selection")
```

This is the way how you use if statement. Therefore, I assume this assignment is for practice if, else if, else.

Comment: I think the second part is what you want. You just have to learn how to put them together.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Area {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner shapes = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type number for area calculation: 1 for Triangle, 2 for Circle, 3 for Rectangle, 0 for none of them\n");
        String m = sc.next();
        switch (m) {
            case "0":
                System.out.println("None of them");
                break;
            case "1":
                System.out.println("This is for Triangle");

                System.out.println("Enter two values to calculate the area of a triangle: ");
                int n1 = shapes.nextInt();
                int n2 = shapes.nextInt();

                areaTriangle(n1, n2);
                break;
            case "2":
                System.out.println("This is for Circle");
                System.out.println("Enter a value to calculate the area of a circle: ");
                double radius = shapes.nextInt();
                areaCircle(radius);

                break;
            case "3":
                System.out.println("This is for Rectangle");
                System.out.println("Enter two values to calculate the area of a rectangle: ");
                int m1 = shapes.nextInt();
                int m2 = shapes.nextInt();

                areaRectangle(m1, m2);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Wrong selection!");

        }
    }

    public static void areaTriangle(int n1, int n2) {
        int areat = (n1 * n2) / 2;
        System.out.println("The area of a triangle with your values is: " + areat);
    }

    public static void areaCircle(double radius) {
        double areac = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
        System.out.println("The area of the circle with your values is: " + areac);
    }

    public static void areaRectangle(int m1, int m2) {
        int arear = (m1 * m2);
        System.out.println("The area of a rectangle with your values is: " + arear);

    }
}
```